# Changing sign at a Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process: mean, variance and likelihood

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

I am working with a multivariate Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process and its statistical properties (likelihood, expected values and variance).

The Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process can be described as a random walk with a deterministic force that move a particle back towards a central location. It is defined from the following stochastic differential equation:

\begin{equation}
dX_{t}=-{\theta}X_t + {\sigma}dW_t
\end{equation}

where the mean is:
\begin{equation}
E[X_t]=E[X_0]e^{-\theta t}
\end{equation}

the covariance is:
\begin{equation}
Cov[X_t,X_s]={\frac {\sigma ^{2}}{2\theta }}\left(e^{-\theta |t-s|}-e^{-\theta (t+s)}\right)
\end{equation}

and variance:
\begin{equation}
Var[X_t]={\frac {\sigma ^{2}}{2\theta }}\left(1-e^{-2\theta (t-t')}\right)
\end{equation}

This represent the case of a one-dimensional (univariate) Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process. The results for a multidimensional Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process are quite similar.
Since the OU process is a Gauss-Markov process, we can calculate the likelihood of the parameters of the model given the data (observations of x at the preset time).

The log-likelihood for a multivariate model with *n* observations at *m* dimensions would take the form of:

\begin{equation}
log(L)=-{\frac{1}{2}[mnlog(2{\pi}} + log|V| + (Y - {\beta}X)^T V^{-1} (Y - {\beta}X)]
\end{equation}

where Y is a *mn* vector of observed values, βX is a matrix of mean values for the *m*-dimensional observations and V is the variance-covariance matrix.

Now, in physics and other disciplines, the OU process is also considered a mean-reverting process. In biology, it is often used to model the evolution of a trait under selection.

I am interested in "reverting the OU process" (not sure this is the proper way of saying). That is, instead of having a "pulling process" forward in time, I am interested in a "pushing process".
I would expect in this case that the mean is:

\begin{equation}
E[X_t]=E[X_0]e^{\theta t}
\end{equation}

And simply change the sign of the exponential (+θ instead of -θ). Would be correct? If it is, I expect that I can also use the same log-likelihood function.

On a more general note, is there a simple and clear way to prove that a given equation follow Gauss-Markov processes and can thus be used in the log-likelihood shown before?

Since I have a training as biologists, some of the terms I used may not be very clear or correct (apologise for this).

Comment: The OU mean reverting allows you to have a steady state for large times (mean is zero, covariance depends only on $t-s$). Namely, there is a state where you have a Weak-Sense Stationary Process, that is a desirable property. Be aware that by changing sign to $\theta$ you loose this nice property.

Comment: I do not know what you mean by pulling, to me $\theta$ is dissipation rate and as such it has to be positive as you can see it in the covariance of $X_t$ and $X_s$ for large time differences. If $\theta$ were positive it would imply stronger correlation of samples that are further away in time, not a fading memory. I cannot think of a physical situation that such model could describe. Notice too that your expectation would increase exponentially with time, too.

Comment: A physical situation for such model would be a particle that start walking around following a deterministic "force" with rate &theta; and a stochastic part given by the brownian random walk (&sigma;). Perhaps, the OU process is not the best model choice. However the idea is that if I reconstruct the movement of the particle backward in time, this should be a classical OU process. Whereas if I model it forward in time, this should be equivalent to a "reverted OU process". What do you think?

Comment: Also, in the question I assumed that theta might get negative values, but what if I consider negative values for the variable t (time)? Would that makes sense?

Comment: Perhaps, what I tried to explain in my question corresponds to a multivariate Geometric Brownian Motion?

Comment: No, it is not a geometric brownian motion: you have additive noise not multiplicative noise https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/746826/226902 see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion