# Geometric Brownian Motion versus Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

The Geometric Brownian Motion model is a continuous-time stochastic process in which a particle move according to a random fluctuations (Wiener process) and a drift term.
The corresponding stochastic differential equation is:

\begin{equation}
dX_{t}=\mu X_{t}dt+\sigma X_{t} dW_{t}
\end{equation}

And the mean is given by:
\begin{equation}
E[X_{t}]=X_{0} e^{\mu t}
\end{equation}

The Geometric Brownian Motion model recalls the Ornstein-Uhlbenck process, which stochastic differential equation is given by:

\begin{equation}
dX_{t}=-\mu X_{t}dt+\sigma dW_{t}
\end{equation}

And the mean is given by:
\begin{equation}
E[X_{t}]=X_{0} e^{-\mu t}
\end{equation}

I have several questions concerning these two models:

1. Could we say that the GBM model is the "reverse-in-time" of the OU process, given the change in sign in front of the drift term? If not, does exist a process equivalent to OU, but with a positive drift term?
2. What are the consequences of having Xt in front of the σ parameter in the GBM model compared to a OU process?
3. What are the covariance and variance expressions for a GBM model?
4. Is the likelihood function the same as a general multivariate normal distribution?

Comment: One could have OU process with negative coefficient, and it would be still OE process. The real difference between the two is the $X_t$ in the noise term.

Comment: Thanks @RogerVadim, but then do you think that I would not violate some assumption when using a negative coefficient? Is there a way to be sure about that?

Comment: You will have an exponentially growing mean, which doesn't make sense in most physical problems... But there are exceptions - like escape over a potential barrier.

Comment: In the application of my interest, it would be equivalent to a travelling wave. In other words, I am modelling spatial movements of a particle that is 'trapped' by a travelling wave, and thus exponentially travel away from its original position. It is also possible to add a limit to this exponential growing mean. Does it make sense to you?